# HTTP Request and parse XML

Tags: ios, xml, swift3, httprequest

I am coming from python and trying to learn swift. In python what I am trying to do is very simple with beautiful soup and requests but I haven't been able to find a way to do this in swift. Most the tutorials I have found are outdated. I have a url that contains a sitemap in xml. It looks like

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>
      http://www.link.com
   </loc>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>
      http://www.link2.com
    </loc>
  </sitemap
</sitemapindex>
```

What I am trying to do is get the contents of the link and parse the xml to go through each  elements. How could I do this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access Apple's Foundation framework (that is, for example, you don't use Swift on linux), there is functionality for both, HTTP requests and XML parsing.

- For HTTP requests, have a look at [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession), which should give you everything you'd expect from a HTTP client.
- For XML parsing, have a look at [XMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmlparser), which is a standard SAX parser.

Both of them are widely used and you should easily find examples in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some third-party libraries

- [Alamofire](https://github.com/alamofire/alamofire) for Http
- [SwiftyXMLParser](https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser) for parse XML

I think these can help you a lot.